# Spring IsFormSubmission with Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to handle `isFormSubmission` with Spring annotations, is there any annotation available to block duplicate submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. And you can't detect it with `isFormSubmission()` - it will tell you only of the request is using `POST` or not.

You can use client-side code to disable duplicate submission (disable the submit button when it's pressed)

Comment: @Bozho:When i click submi button,it is passing two requests.What is the use here to disable the submit button.

Comment: @user569125 it's not possible for a single submit button to fire two requests. Unless you use javascript to submit the form in addition to the regular submission.

Comment: @user569125 how come it is passing two requests? Unless you submit the form twice, the browser will send only one request.

Comment: furthermore - you can't use isFormSubmission for detecting duplicate submissions. It will return true when POST method is used.

Comment: @ Bozho:This is my Form design,<form action="test.do" name="test><div><form action="test.do" name="test1"></form></div></form>.nested form i am calling with js function.Is this causing issue.

Comment: you can't have nested forms. Drop that idea. And anyway - post the code you use to submit it. Let us know the whole picture so that a proper answer can be given.